# MYSQL query to find a row that does not exist

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi

Consider the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Raspberry_data(
  Slave_ID INT,
  Serial VARCHAR(30),
  Quantity INT,
  Current_Operation INT,
  ID INT,
  Raspberry_ID INT
  );
  
  INSERT INTO Raspberry_data (SLave_ID,Serial,Quantity,Current_operation,ID,Raspberry_ID)
  VALUES (1,"55555",50,0,1,1),
  (3,"33333",33,0,3,1),
  (4,"12345",33,0,3,1),
  (6,"44444",33,0,3,1),
  (7,"44444",33,0,3,1);
```

I am using Python program and doing some MYSQL operations. First of all, I check how many "active devices" I have connected to my Raspberry PI. In my circumstanes this number can be any number from 0 to 15. I save this number and their ID's in active_devices list (because the ID's might not be in order).

After I know how many active devices are connected to Raspberry PI, I use for loop to check the records with their ID on MYSQL database: Snippet of my code:

```
    print("Active devices found=",len(active_devices))
    for x in range(0,len(active_devices)):  
        query = "SELECT Quantity,Serial FROM Raspberry_data WHERE Slave_ID = %s AND Raspberry_ID = %s"
        cur.execute(query,(active_devices[x],Raspberry_ID))
        for Quantity,Serial in cur.fetchall() :
            serial_to_send = []
            serial_to_send.extend([3,int(Quantity),active_devices[x],len(Serial)])
            for y in range(0,len(Serial)):
                serial_to_send.append(ord(Serial[y]))
            print("active device data = ",serial_to_send)
            while True:
                try:
                    master_modbus.execute(int(active_devices[x]), cst.WRITE_MULTIPLE_REGISTERS, 10,4+len(Serial),serial_to_send)
                    break
                except Exception as e:
                    print("exception on restart:",e)
```

If there is a MYSQL record for that ID, I send some data over to that device. My problem is, that if there is no MYSQL record for a particular ID,I want to send something else to that device but my SQL query

```
query = "SELECT Quantity, Serial FROM Raspberry_data WHERE Slave_ID = %s AND Raspberry_ID = %s"
```

only returns the rows that exists.

Can someone help me figure out how can I also get the ID's that does not have any record in MySQL table?

I am adding a MySQL database example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kbZNr1hh7Fq4vcnr1gtu12/0

Note that in this table, there are no records where Slave_ID = 2 and Slave_ID = 5. In my Python program, I need to know that ID 2 and 5 Have no records.

Comment: you already have the list of active devices, just remove the one present in the database - it is as simple as that. just add ID in the SELECT clause.

Comment: There's also no 8, so why don't we want to know about that?

Comment: And note that, by convention, a column called 'id' usually refers to the (surrogate) primary key of that table. If that's not the case (and plainly it isn't), consider renaming that column.